# The error of torch.compile with the cuda12.1?

Tags: deep-learning, torch

I want to use the function of pytorch2.0 of the torch.compile();

THE enviriment:
ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
nvidiaA40  driver 530.30.02
cuda version 12.1
torch2.0.1+cuda118

my pytorch code:

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
model = models.resnet18().cuda()
torch.set_float32_matmul_precision('high')
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
compiled_model = torch.compile(model)
x = torch.randn(16, 3, 224, 224).cuda()
optimizer.zero_grad()
out = compiled_model(x)
out.sum().backward()
optimizer.step()
```

when no cuda in the code,the compile run sucessfuly
but the code above meet a error

```
Bearing1_1
2803
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 246, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py", line 549, in _worker_compile
    kernel.precompile(warm_cache_only_with_cc=cc)
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/triton_ops/autotune.py", line 69, in precompile
    self.launchers = [
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/triton_ops/autotune.py", line 70, in 
    self._precompile_config(c, warm_cache_only_with_cc)
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/triton_ops/autotune.py", line 83, in _precompile_config
    triton.compile(
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/triton/compiler.py", line 1239, in compile
    so = _build(fn.__name__, src_path, tmpdir)
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/triton/compiler.py", line 1169, in _build
    ret = subprocess.check_call(cc_cmd)
  File "/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/gcc', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/main.c', '-O3', '-I/usr/local/cuda/include', '-I/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/include/python3.9', '-I/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e', '-shared', '-fPIC', '-lcuda', '-o', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/triton_.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '-L/usr/share/man/man7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py in call_user_compiler(self, gm)
    669             else:
--> 670                 compiled_fn = compiler_fn(gm, self.fake_example_inputs())
    671             _step_logger()(logging.INFO, f"done compiler function {name}")

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/debug_utils.py in debug_wrapper(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
   1054         else:
-> 1055             compiled_gm = compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
   1056 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py in __call__(self, model_, inputs_)
   1389 
-> 1390         return compile_fx(model_, inputs_, config_patches=self.config)
   1391 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py in compile_fx(model_, example_inputs_, inner_compile, config_patches)
    454         # once torchdynamo is merged into pytorch
--> 455         return aot_autograd(
    456             fw_compiler=fw_compiler,

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/backends/common.py in compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
     47             with enable_aot_logging():
---> 48                 cg = aot_module_simplified(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
     49                 counters["aot_autograd"]["ok"] += 1

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py in aot_module_simplified(mod, args, fw_compiler, bw_compiler, partition_fn, decompositions, hasher_type, static_argnums, keep_inference_input_mutations)
   2821 
-> 2822     compiled_fn = create_aot_dispatcher_function(
   2823         functional_call,

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py in time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    162             t0 = time.time()
--> 163             r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    164             time_spent = time.time() - t0

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py in create_aot_dispatcher_function(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config)
   2514 
-> 2515         compiled_fn = compiler_fn(flat_fn, fake_flat_args, aot_config)
   2516 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py in aot_wrapper_dedupe(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config, compiler_fn)
   1714         if ok:
-> 1715             return compiler_fn(flat_fn, leaf_flat_args, aot_config)
   1716 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_functorch/aot_autograd.py in aot_dispatch_autograd(flat_fn, flat_args, aot_config)
   2149         with track_graph_compiling(aot_config, "forward"):
-> 2150             compiled_fw_func = aot_config.fw_compiler(
   2151                 fw_module, flat_args_with_views_handled

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py in time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    162             t0 = time.time()
--> 163             r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    164             time_spent = time.time() - t0

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py in fw_compiler(model, example_inputs)
    429         model = convert_outplace_to_inplace(model)
--> 430         return inner_compile(
    431             model,

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/debug_utils.py in debug_wrapper(gm, example_inputs, **kwargs)
    594         else:
--> 595             compiled_fn = compiler_fn(gm, example_inputs)
    596 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/debug.py in inner(*args, **kwargs)
    238             with DebugContext():
--> 239                 return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    240 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py in inner(*args, **kwds)
     78             with self._recreate_cm():
---> 79                 return func(*args, **kwds)
     80         return inner

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/compile_fx.py in compile_fx_inner(gm, example_inputs, cudagraphs, num_fixed, is_backward, graph_id)
    176             graph.run(*example_inputs)
--> 177             compiled_fn = graph.compile_to_fn()
    178 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py in compile_to_fn(self)
    585     def compile_to_fn(self):
--> 586         return self.compile_to_module().call
    587 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py in time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    162             t0 = time.time()
--> 163             r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    164             time_spent = time.time() - t0

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py in compile_to_module(self)
    574 
--> 575         mod = PyCodeCache.load(code)
    576         for name, value in self.constants.items():

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py in load(cls, source_code)
    527                 mod.key = key
--> 528                 exec(code, mod.__dict__, mod.__dict__)
    529                 # another thread might set this first

/tmp/torchinductor_yangtao/fm/cfmpd4ah5cxsf2zqxmer4ty7g5nmxbksa4sj4mhf3m7tazpzcmbm.py in 
   1333 
-> 1334 async_compile.wait(globals())
   1335 del async_compile

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py in wait(self, scope)
    714                 if isinstance(result, (Future, TritonFuture)):
--> 715                     scope[key] = result.result()
    716                     pbar.update(1)

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_inductor/codecache.py in result(self)
    572         # If the worker failed this will throw an exception.
--> 573         self.future.result()
    574         kernel = self.kernel = _load_kernel(self.source_code)

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    445                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 446                     return self.__get_result()
    447                 else:

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    390             try:
--> 391                 raise self._exception
    392             finally:

CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/gcc', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/main.c', '-O3', '-I/usr/local/cuda/include', '-I/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/include/python3.9', '-I/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e', '-shared', '-fPIC', '-lcuda', '-o', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/triton_.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '-L/usr/share/man/man7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

BackendCompilerFailed                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2813066/234096864.py in 
      7 x = torch.randn(16, 3, 224, 224).cuda()
      8 optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 9 out = compiled_model(x)
     10 out.sum().backward()
     11 optimizer.step()

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py in forward(self, *args, **kwargs)
     80 
     81     def forward(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 82         return self.dynamo_ctx(self._orig_mod.forward)(*args, **kwargs)
     83 
     84 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py in _fn(*args, **kwargs)
    207             dynamic_ctx.__enter__()
    208             try:
--> 209                 return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    210             finally:
    211                 set_eval_frame(prior)

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/eval_frame.py in catch_errors(frame, cache_size)
    335 
    336         with compile_lock:
--> 337             return callback(frame, cache_size, hooks)
    338 
    339     catch_errors._torchdynamo_orig_callable = callback  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py in _convert_frame(frame, cache_size, hooks)
    402         counters["frames"]["total"] += 1
    403         try:
--> 404             result = inner_convert(frame, cache_size, hooks)
    405             counters["frames"]["ok"] += 1
    406             return result

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py in _fn(*args, **kwargs)
    102         torch.fx.graph_module._forward_from_src = fx_forward_from_src_skip_result
    103         try:
--> 104             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    105         finally:
    106             torch._C._set_grad_enabled(prior_grad_mode)

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py in _convert_frame_assert(frame, cache_size, hooks)
    260         initial_grad_state = torch.is_grad_enabled()
    261 
--> 262         return _compile(
    263             frame.f_code,
    264             frame.f_globals,

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py in time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    161                 compilation_metrics[key] = []
    162             t0 = time.time()
--> 163             r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    164             time_spent = time.time() - t0
    165             # print(f"Dynamo timer: key={key}, latency={latency:.2f} sec")

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py in _compile(code, globals, locals, builtins, compiler_fn, one_graph, export, hooks, frame)
    322         for attempt in itertools.count():
    323             try:
--> 324                 out_code = transform_code_object(code, transform)
    325                 orig_code_map[out_code] = code
    326                 break

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/bytecode_transformation.py in transform_code_object(code, transformations, safe)
    443     propagate_line_nums(instructions)
    444 
--> 445     transformations(instructions, code_options)
    446     return clean_and_assemble_instructions(instructions, keys, code_options)[1]
    447 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/convert_frame.py in transform(instructions, code_options)
    309             mutated_closure_cell_contents,
    310         )
--> 311         tracer.run()
    312         output = tracer.output
    313         assert output is not None

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py in run(self)
   1724     def run(self):
   1725         _step_logger()(logging.INFO, f"torchdynamo start tracing {self.f_code.co_name}")
-> 1726         super().run()
   1727 
   1728     def match_nested_cell(self, name, cell):

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py in run(self)
    574                 self.instruction_pointer is not None
    575                 and not self.output.should_exit
--> 576                 and self.step()
    577             ):
    578                 pass

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py in step(self)
    538             if not hasattr(self, inst.opname):
    539                 unimplemented(f"missing: {inst.opname}")
--> 540             getattr(self, inst.opname)(inst)
    541 
    542             return inst.opname != "RETURN_VALUE"

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/symbolic_convert.py in RETURN_VALUE(self, inst)
   1790         )
   1791         log.debug("RETURN_VALUE triggered compile")
-> 1792         self.output.compile_subgraph(
   1793             self, reason=GraphCompileReason("return_value", [self.frame_summary()])
   1794         )

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py in compile_subgraph(self, tx, partial_convert, reason)
    515             # optimization to generate better code in a common case
    516             self.add_output_instructions(
--> 517                 self.compile_and_call_fx_graph(tx, list(reversed(stack_values)), root)
    518                 + [create_instruction("UNPACK_SEQUENCE", len(stack_values))]
    519             )

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py in compile_and_call_fx_graph(self, tx, rv, root)
    586         assert_no_fake_params_or_buffers(gm)
    587         with tracing(self.tracing_context):
--> 588             compiled_fn = self.call_user_compiler(gm)
    589         compiled_fn = disable(compiled_fn)
    590 

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/utils.py in time_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    161                 compilation_metrics[key] = []
    162             t0 = time.time()
--> 163             r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    164             time_spent = time.time() - t0
    165             # print(f"Dynamo timer: key={key}, latency={latency:.2f} sec")

~/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/output_graph.py in call_user_compiler(self, gm)
    673         except Exception as e:
    674             compiled_fn = gm.forward
--> 675             raise BackendCompilerFailed(self.compiler_fn, e) from e
    676         return compiled_fn
    677 

BackendCompilerFailed: debug_wrapper raised CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/gcc', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/main.c', '-O3', '-I/usr/local/cuda/include', '-I/userhome/home/yangtao/anaconda3/envs/dl2.0/include/python3.9', '-I/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e', '-shared', '-fPIC', '-lcuda', '-o', '/tmp/tmp6tv6oc9e/triton_.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '-L/usr/share/man/man7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Set torch._dynamo.config.verbose=True for more information


You can suppress this exception and fall back to eager by setting:
    torch._dynamo.config.suppress_errors = True
```

I try on another server with torch and cuda11.7 the same code run successfully
what's wrong with the environment,how can i adjust it without connect with my server manager;